# Printing high quality images in Java

Tags: java, printing, javacv

I'm currently struggling with the lack of information on the web about printing in Java in general and printing high quality images specifically.

My current situation is that i'm grabbing a couple of frames from a 720p web camera through JavaCV and I need to print them on a page as close to the original quality as possible. Currently I'm using a JFrame to align and print the images and text being the Java noob that I am, However, this does not produce the desired quality.

What is the way to print higher quality imgs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do that in Java or could you simply print out a PNG file or something using a common native tool you may have?

Comment: @SamuelAudet the images need to be printed in a specific alignment, but yeah, it is possible to use native tool (I'm on Windows) - Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just call `cvSaveImage("image.png", image)` and print `image.png` with GIMP or anyway something that works well with your printer drivers?